# Java SOAP request

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

In the course of my self education with SOAP I am trying to make a request:
1. For my tests I took a trader's api [wsdl](http://client-api.instaforex.com/soapservices/ClientTrading.svc?wsdl).
2. With the help of `maven-jaxb2-plugin` generated java classes.
3. Among the others there are such as: `ObjectFactory, TokenRequest, TokenResponse, GetInfoRequest`.
4. I am making new objects through the `ObjectFactory` and as I think I am doing a request:

```
ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
TokenRequest tokenRequest = factory.createTokenRequest();
tokenRequest.setLogin(12345);
tokenRequest.setPassword(factory.createTokenRequestPassword("password"));
TokenResponse tokenResponse = factory.createTokenResponse();
GetInfoRequest getInfoRequest = factory.createGetInfoRequest();
getInfoRequest.getLogin();  //It's null
```

Why do I get null there (have I missed something)? Do I even make a request? How can I track if I really make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I even make a request?

No, you are not doing a request, you are just creating objects over there

check in your generated classes for two classes called `ClientTradingService` and `IClientTradingApi` you have to use those to do the request.

```
ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
TokenRequest tokenRequest = factory.createTokenRequest();
tokenRequest.setLogin(12345);
tokenRequest.setPassword(factory.createTokenRequestPassword("password"));

//create your service should be something similar to this 
ClientTradingService service = new ClientTradingService();
IClientTradingApi iservice = service.getBasicHttpBindingIClientTradingApi();

//do your request should be something similar to this 
TokenResponse tokenResponse = iservice.getAuthenticationToken(tokenRequest);

//now you can get the info from the response 
tokenResponse.getToken();//this should return the authentication token
```

To do some other request the process is exactly as the one above.

Comment: I got it. The problem is that I don't have those generated ClientTradingApi classes. Could that be a problem of the plugin generator?

Comment: @IgorZ some times they don't get generated in the same package

Comment: Really, maven plugin does not make that service. I took wsimport.exe -keep -verbose http://...wsdl and it made ClientTradingService.java among the others. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the WSDL then in the below section you will find **wsdl:portType name="IClientTradingApi"** and 
        **service name="ClientTradingService"**.
you have to use those class for calling the service.
Below code may help you.

```
    ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
    TokenRequest tokenRequest = factory.createTokenRequest();
    tokenRequest.setLogin(12345);
    tokenRequest.setPassword(factory.createTokenRequestPassword("password"));
    ClientTradingService service = new ClientTradingService();
    IClientTradingApi iClientTradingApi = 
    service.getBasicHttpBindingIClientTradingApi();
    TokenResponse response = 
    iClientTradingApi.getAuthenticationToken(tokenRequest);
    System.out.println(response);
```